# How to adjust product listings in Magento

Tags: magento

I am looking at a friend's Magento setup and I have never used Magento until recently.

I am trying to change a product listing that has a bug. Here is the link to the products: http://shop.crystalvine.com/salt.html

They are mostly ok, but if you click on "Tart Cherry Salt" it takes you to a url like this: http://shop.crystalvine.com/salt/white-zinfandel.html which is named zinfindel.

How do I do it so that it takes the user to the url for the cherry salt?

I am in the Magento console and I clicked on the catalog pane, and went under categories and found the listing of products. But I don't see how to edit the link from the `salt.html` page.

Any idea how to make that change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working fine, clicking on "Tart Cherry Salt" took me to: 
http://shop.crystalvine.com/salt/tart-cherry-salt.html

Which is exactly where you want to go.

Perhaps you can refresh your browser cache.

Did you perhaps set a product and then rename it? 
Did you duplicate a product to create "Tart Cherry Salt" or did you create that product from scratch?